# JQuery Mobile checking for hash on load

Tags: jquery-mobile

http://site.com/#pagename

I would usually use the jquery.address plugin to get any hash value (pagename) from the incoming url and then load the appropriate page.
I'm new to jquery mobile. Could someone tell me whether this functionality is built into the framework or whether I am best using a plugin.
Any help much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it

$.mobile.path.parseUrl

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash` also returns the hash of the current URL. Here's some info about the `window.location` object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp